# Concatenar valores no gráfico JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

Como concatenar valores no jfreechart?

Estou tentando deste modo:

```
public static DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();;

    public void atualizaDataset(int humano, int zumbi, int rodada){
        final String series1 = "Humano";
        final String series2 = "Zumbi";

        dataset.addValue(humano, series1, (Comparable)rodada);
        dataset.addValue(zumbi, series2, (Comparable)rodada);
    }
```

Porém não estou obtendo sucesso, ele executa a primeira vez que mando, mas quando eu mando a segunda ele adiciona como se fossem os primeiros valores, eles nao concatenam!

Comment: Você está usando esse exemplo http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartLineChartDemo1.htm?

Comment: Sim, este mesmo

Comment: Você quer adicionar os valores pela sua main?

Comment: Sim adicionar pela main

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer os seguinte, criar um construtor que recebe um `CategoryDataset`

```
public LineChartDemo1(final String title, CategoryDataset dataset) {
        super(title);
        final CategoryDataset dataset = dataset;
        final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 270));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);
}
```

e no seu `main()`:

```
 DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
//adiciona valores aqui
final LineChartDemo1 demo = new LineChartDemo1("Line Chart Demo", dataset);
//resto do código
```

Caso você adicione depois de ter construído o gráfico, será necessário reconstruir(repaint) ele.

Comment: Mase esse método nao vai refazer o grafico com os valores novos ao invés de só adicioanr eles juntos aos ja existentes?

Comment: Sim, ele gera um gráfico. Se você quiser adicionar ao existente é diferente, é só adicionar no dataset e fazer um repaint.

Comment: Mas é essa minha duvida. Como eu atualizo o dataset sem recriar o grafico ? Atualizei a postagem com o codigo atual. Tentei criar o dataset como global e ir adicionando valores nele, mas ainda nao deu muito certo.